# wrong output while reading file

Tags: c, string, file, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a matrix. As i will have several files with unknown amounts of rows and columns, i allocated memory for the matrix dynamically.

My code until now.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char** map, chr;
    int column = 0, row = 0, columns = 0, rows = 0, total_elements = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

    // count numbers of rows and columns
    while (chr != EOF)
    {   
        if (chr == '\n')
        {
            rows = rows + 1;
        }
        chr = getc(file);
        total_elements+=1;
    }

    rows += 1;
    
    //Dividing the total number of elements by the number of rows to find the number of columns
    columns = (total_elements/rows) - 1;

    // alocate space for matrix
    map = (char **) malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));

    // allocating space for each column of each row
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        map[row] = (char *) malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
    }

    // file reading
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            if (!fscanf(file, "%c", &map[row][column]))
                break;
            printf("%c", map[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(map);


    return 0;
```

This is the file:

```
....*.....................
..........................
........*........*........
.....*....................
...............*....*.....
..*.......*...............
............*.............
..........................
..............*...........
..................*.......
..*.......*......*........
....*..*..................
...**.....................
..........*...............
....................*.....
..........................
....**....................
......................*...
```

­The expected output would be the contents of the file, but i get the output in the wrong format.

```
?Å É/Å @Q▓v            @Q
­?Å É/Å             xA¢v
­?Å É/Å  ÊÐ C Å └ Å µ
­?Å É/Å     
­?Å É/Å
­?Å É/Å         T(Å     P(
­?Å É/Å @Q▓v            @Q
­?Å É/Å             xA¢vx(
­?Å É/Å ╩  ╩ÈÐ  └ Å É&Å ug
­?Å É/Å ┼  ┼═Ð  └ Å É&Å ├
­?Å É/Å     
­?Å É/Å  H
­?Å É/Å 
­?Å É/Å 
­?Å É/Å 
░Å É/Å
ä
 H
```

I really don't know where i could have made the mistake to make this happen.

Comment: First of all: `getc` return an `int` not a `char`. A `char` might not be able to distinguish valid value from `EOF`.

Comment: To begin with there are two errors with `char chr` which should be `int chr`, and `while (chr != EOF)` checks it before any value has been written to it. Deal with any compiler warning.

Comment: @Gerhardh A `char` will almost certainly be able to hold EOF, as EOF is usually -1.  The problem is that a char cannot distinguish between a valid data point and an EOF.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you're right. I used bad wording.

Comment: The code checks the value of the uninitialized `chr`.  That is undefined behavior.  Fix that first.  (Use the standard idiom!)

Comment: You must `rewind(file)` before the second reading. And you should not check `fscanf` with `0` but with the number of conversions expected (because `EOF` isn't `0`).

Comment: I'm not sure that "i allocated memory for the matrix dynamically." is accurate.  Normally, that would mean that you allocate data as needed during the read.  You're making multiple passes on the data (well, you're trying to, but you forgot to rewind) and allocating once.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I would suggest *I allocated dynamic memory for the matrix*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the type of file you are reading and the way you are allocating memory, there is no need to read the whole file twice:

```
.....*....................
...............*....*.....
..*.......*...............
............*.............
```

The data is line oriented and --- I suppose --- all lines have the same number of columns. And the data will be stored at

```
    char **map;
```

an array of pointers, so each `map[i]` is `char*` and can hold a line of data.

`fscanf()` was written for consume tabular data, with possible delimiters and different field types, like *csv* files with many `int` and `float` data separated by `#` for example. There is not much sense in using `fscanf()` to read chars and you could use `fgetc()` or `fread()` instead.

#### about your code

- as already told, you need to `rewind` the file to read the data again
- also, as told, you need to test for `'\n'` since it is not data
- always test `fscanf()` return against the number of specifiers

The loop below would consume your file considering what I said above

```
    rewind(file);
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
    while (1 == fscanf(file, "%c", &map[row][column]))
    {
        if (map[row][column] == '\n')
        {   row += 1, column = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {   printf("%c", map[row][column]);
            column += 1;
        }
    };  // while();
    fclose(file);
```

In general is more manageable to use the map data in a flat memory area, using just `char*`, in the C way, and storing the map line after line, instead of using `char**`

#### a more flexible way

Using the `char**` way, you can read the data in lines and keep the map as strings as it may be useful to display and use, while still using

```
map[][]
```

for reference.

**I will show you an example**

Also, since you said you have many file sizes you should consider passing the file name as a parameter

To have more control you could use some encapsulation and put the data in a `struct` like

```
typedef struct
{
    int    cols;
    int    rows;
    int    size;
    char** map;

} Grid;
```

This way you can have a function like

```
int   show_grid(Grid*,const char*);
```

and write

```
    char title[100];
    sprintf(title, "\n    Map for %s\n",file_name);
    show_grid(&gr, title);
```

To see on screen

```
    Map for file.txt

[18 rows, 26 columns]
....*.....................
..........................
........*........*........
.....*....................
...............*....*.....
..*.......*...............
............*.............
..........................
..............*...........
..................*.......
..*.......*......*........
....*..*..................
...**.....................
..........*...............
....................*.....
..........................
....**....................
......................*...
```

And the code can be simple as 4 lines:

```
void show_grid(Grid* g, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("[%d rows, %d columns]\n",
        g->rows, g->cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < g->rows; i+=1)
        printf("%s\n", g->map[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

#### determining the column size

```
    int ch = 0;
    for (gr.cols = 0; ch != '\n'; gr.cols += 1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(F);
        if (feof(F)) return -2;
    }
```

You just need to find the end of the first line, since all rows have the same size and the memory is allocated in lines.

In the case of using `char*` and a flat area it may the simpler just to allocate an area as large as the file, using `stat` or `ftell` to get the file size instead of reading the file twice.

#### allocating memory in blocks of rows

It is faster to use this way, and read the data using `fgets()` to consume a whole line per call. Also, since the data is not flat anyway, you can keep the lines as strings to simplify the display. see:

```
    // blocksize in lines
    int row = 0;
    while (!feof(F))
    {
        gr.map[row] = (char*)malloc(gr.cols);  // new row
        fgets(gr.map[row], gr.cols, F);
        gr.map[row][gr.cols - 2] = 0;
        row += 1;
        if (row == gr.size)
        {  // expand block
            int    new_size = gr.size + BLKSIZE;
            char** temp = (char**)realloc(gr.map, sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (temp == NULL) break;
            gr.map  = temp;
            gr.size = new_size;
        };
    };
    fclose(F);
```

You can have a suitable `BLKSIZE` to not resize many times.

#### passing the file name on the command line

This way you can have a default, but also pass the file name in the command line so it can be used in a script. And since the display function conveniently shows the file name you can check any number of files easily as in

```
    // open file as 'F'
    const char* default_file_name = "file.txt";
    char        file_name[80];
    FILE*       F            = NULL;
    if (argc > 1) 
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(file_name, default_file_name);

    F = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (F == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return -1;
    }
```

#### Example

```
SO> .\f0-0922

    Map for file.txt

[18 rows, 26 columns]
....*.....................
..........................
........*........*........
.....*....................
...............*....*.....
..*.......*...............
............*.............
..........................
..............*...........
..................*.......
..*.......*......*........
....*..*..................
...**.....................
..........*...............
....................*.....
..........................
....**....................
......................*...

SO> .\f0-0922 other.txt

    Map for other.txt

[5 rows, 5 columns]
....*
...*.
..*..
.*...
*....
```

#### code for the examle

```
#define BLKSIZE 20

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int    cols;
    int    rows;
    int    size;
    char** map;

} Grid;

void  show_grid(Grid*,const char*);
void  free_grid(Grid*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // open file as 'F'
    const char* default_file_name = "file.txt";
    char        file_name[80];
    FILE*       F            = NULL;
    if (argc > 1) 
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(file_name, default_file_name);

    F = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (F == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return -1;
    }

    // define grid
    Grid gr = {0, 0, 0, NULL};

    // set 'cols' to column size
    int ch = 0;
    for (gr.cols = 0; ch != '\n'; gr.cols += 1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(F);
        if (feof(F)) return -2;
    }
    gr.cols = gr.cols + 1;  // add space to a terminating 0
    rewind(F);              // roll back 1st line
    gr.map = (char**)malloc((BLKSIZE * gr.cols) * sizeof(char*));  // initial size
    gr.size = BLKSIZE;

    // blocksize in lines
    int row = 0;
    while (!feof(F))
    {
        gr.map[row] = (char*)malloc(gr.cols);  // new row
        fgets(gr.map[row], gr.cols, F);
        gr.map[row][gr.cols - 2] = 0;
        row += 1;
        if (row == gr.size)
        {  // expand block
            int    new_size = gr.size + BLKSIZE;
            char** temp = (char**)realloc(gr.map, sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (temp == NULL) break;
            gr.map  = temp;
            gr.size = new_size;
        };
    };
    fclose(F);

    gr.rows = row;
    gr.cols -= 2;

    char title[100];
    sprintf(title, "\n    Map for %s\n",file_name);
    show_grid(&gr, title);
    free_grid(&gr);

    return 0;
}

void show_grid(Grid* g, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("[%d rows, %d columns]\n", g->rows, g->cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < g->rows; i += 1) printf("%s\n", g->map[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void free_grid(Grid* g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < g->rows; i += 1) free(g->map[i]);
    free(g->map);
    g->map = NULL;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char **map, chr;
    int column = 0, row = 0, columns = 0, rows = 0, total_elements = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

    // count numbers of rows and columns

    while (1) {
        chr = (char) getc(file);

        if (chr == EOF)
            break;

        if (chr == '\n') {
            rows = rows + 1;
        } else {
            //\n is not part of matrix
            total_elements += 1;
        }

    }

    rows += 1;

    printf("%d,%d\n", total_elements, rows); //no need -1 since did not counted \n

//Dividing the total number of elements by the number of rows to find the number of columns
    columns = (total_elements / rows);

// alocate space for matrix
    map = (char **) malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));

// allocating space for each column of each row
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        map[row] = (char *) malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
    }

//fix offset
    rewind(file);
// file reading
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            chr = (char) getc(file);
            map[row][column] = chr;
        }
        chr = (char) getc(file); //read \n but not write to array
    }
    row = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            printf("%c", map[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(map);


    return 0;
}
```